# Why does the Clio Users endpoint always return a contact object that is null?

Tags: api, clio-api

I'm trying to create metrics about matters and tie the metrics to associated users and contacts. I'm able to successfully pull data from the Matters, Users, and Contacts endpoints; however, the API Document suggest that there should be a 'contact' object that can be return from the Users endpoint that will have the contact id. The problem is that this object is always null. Can anyone tell me why that is and how to fix it?

Here's the documentation:

https://app.clio.com/api/v4/documentation#operation/User#index

here is my postman request that I'm using to verify that I'm retrieving the data I need before hitting the endpoint with my app.

https://www.getpostman.com/collections/4f7e3660330fe912c2d5

### This is an example of the json I might retrieve:

```
{
"data": [
{
"account_owner": true,
"clio_connect": true,
"court_rules_default_attendee": true,
"default_calendar_id": 0,
"email": "string",
"enabled": true,
"etag": "string",
"first_name": "string",
"id": 0,
"initials": "string",
"last_name": "string",
"name": "string",
"phone_number": "string",
"rate": 0,
"subscription_type": "Attorney",
"time_zone": "string",
"roles": [],
"created_at": "2019-04-17T15:23:02Z",
"updated_at": "2019-04-17T15:23:02Z",
"default_activity_description": [],
"notification_methods": [],
"account": [],
"avatar": [],
***"contact": [
{
"id": 0,
"etag": "string",
"name": "string",
"first_name": "string",
"middle_name": "string",
"last_name": "string",
"type": "Company",
"created_at": "2019-04-17T15:23:02Z",
"updated_at": "2019-04-17T15:23:02Z",
"prefix": "string",
"title": "string",
"initials": "string",
"clio_connect_email": "string",
"locked_clio_connect_email": true,
"client_connect_user_id": 0,
"primary_email_address": "string",
"primary_phone_number": "string",
"ledes_client_id": "string",
"is_client": true
}
]***,
"job_title": []
}
]
}
```

### This is what I actually get:

Note: I did not retrieve all of the possible properties.

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 344993632,
            "etag": "\"14902f605c2616c56a68f6d0d2c36334\"",
            "name": "Clio SetUp",
            "first_name": "Clio",
            "last_name": "SetUp",
            "phone_number": null,
            "initials": "CS",
            "default_calendar_id": 852014,
            "subscription_type": "Attorney",
            "email": "frances.bourikas+h@clio.com",
            "created_at": "2017-06-22T15:16:10-06:00",
            "updated_at": "2018-12-28T05:27:49-07:00",
            "roles": [
                "admin"
            ],
            "job_title": null,
            "account": {
                "id": 809498454,
                "etag": "\"303ff7565c8c22be6a68f6d0d2c36334\"",
                "name": "Hoglund, Chwialkowski & Mrozik",
                "state": "paid"
            },
            ***"contact": null***
        },

...
}
```

Comment: Can you post the URL with query params that you are using? The Postman link just has the response

Answer (score 0):

Check the syntax of your GET request. The syntax is tricky, but it should be something similar to:

https://app.clio.com/api/v4/users.json?fields=id,name,first_name,last_name,email,enabled,account_owner,phone_number,rate,subscription_type,time_zone,account{id},contact{id,name,first_name,last_name,type,primary_email_address,primary_phone_number,is_client}created_at,updated_at

URL-encoded of course.